# "Position" or "Rank" for high score table?

Tags: differences

I'm making a game that has a high score table. When I show the player his position/rank in relation to other players, for example on his profile, should I use the word "Position" or "Rank"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In games, you'd usually say 'rank', which is used as a 'competitive' relation in terms of a specific aspect, such as performance. Position is often not used in this context.